# Array displays zero length and no value with each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am more familiar with PHP than with JQuery and kind of stuck on arrays. I have read just about all the posts on the forum on this subject but can't get it to work.

I have what I believe to be an array.
Something that would look like this in php

```
myArr = ['option-4' => '3','option-1' => '8', 'option-3' => '0' ];
```

In JQuery I can retrieve the values by use of the command

```
var x = myArr['option-1'];
```

This all works fine but what I need to do is make a string of the values. So I need to loop through the elements and add the value of the element to the string. The problem is the loop.

When I check the length of the array

```
alert("Elements in array "+myArr.length);
```

it always returns zero.

When I try something like

```
$.each(myArr , function(i, val) { 
  alert(myArr[i]); 
});
```

Nothing shows.

I am missing something obviously, my PHP knowledge must be blocking things.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: In Javascript, something like that would be an object, not an array. Javascript allows you to access objects using array indexing syntax, but they're not arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a valid JavaScript array. You want to use an object:

```
var myArr = {'option-4': '3', 'option-1': '8', 'option-3': '0' };
```

You can then iterate over all keys using a for .. in:

```
for (var key in myArr) {
    alert(myArr[key]);
}
```

This is equivalent to a associative array in PHP. Note that you need to use the explicit key to access an element, you cannot use an index, eg `myArr[0]`.

Comment: Numeric indexes on objects are treated like keys too, though. It is possible to set up a so called "array-like object" with a _length_ property and respective indexes. (Can't test it right now to be sure since jsFiddle is taking for ever right now. I think _0 != '0'_ when used as keys...)

Comment: Like I said, that is what it would look like in PHP. I tried the loop you supplied and it works. Guess it is a valid JavaScript array after all. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
$.each(myArr , function(key, val) { 
  alert(key + ": " + val); 
});
```