# Object, Array and $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I thought I solved my problem using the for (var key in arr) suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283201/array-displays-zero-length-and-no-value-with-each) but this causes trouble in IE. Now I am back to square one.

```
var myVariable = [];

myVariable['option-1'] = 'something';
myVariable['option-2'] = 'something else';
$.each(myVariable, function(index, value) {
  alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

It doesn't work. Nothing shows. Can someone edit it to make it work?

Comment: Array methods don't support named properties. Use an `Object` (`{}`) *( not an `Array` (`[]`) )* and a `for ... in` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an object instead of an array:

```
var myVariable = {};
```

Comment: it is confusing when code works perfectly fine in two browsers (FF and Chrome) and not at all in another (IE). With the change you suggested even IE seems to understand my code. Tnx

Comment: That's interesting, you may have bumped into a jQuery bug; I'll look into it. In any case, you should always use an object if you need named keys.

Comment: IE added elements that were not there. If the object/array had two elements myVariable['options-2'] = 3 and myVariable['options-5'] = 1. Then in IE it would have a third element myVariable['indexOf'] the value was a whole function.

Comment: @RST My IE skills are a little rusty. Do you mean IE has indexOf as an enumerable property on Array.prototype? Only if we're talking about IE<=8, right? Newer IE versions have native support to that method, and it should not be enumerable (I hope they didn't screw *that* up).

Comment: With for...in...{alert(key)...} would show 2 alerts in FF/Chrome and 3 alerts in IE. It was IE8 comp.mode., which seems to be IE7

Answer (score 3):

Change `var myVariable = [];` to `var myVariable = {};`.

The syntax that you're using, `myVariable['option-1'] = 'something';` is for objects, not arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`myVariable` is an array. To add things to an array you use `myVariable.push('something')`. You are using square bracket syntax, which is how you would normally add properties to an object.

Since arrays are objects, you can still access `option-1`, but it is not a member of the array, it is a property of the object: `myVariable['option-1']; // "something"`

The solution is to set `myVariable` to an object. jQuery's `each` method will iterate over the properties of the object as expected.

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery. 
Just use a `for..in` loop (with an object `{}` not an array `[]`):

```
for(var index in myVariable) {
   var value = myVariable[index];
   alert(index + ': ' + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[There are no associative arrays in JavaScript, and non-numeric properties on arrays are bad practise!](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

Instead, use an *object* literal:

```
var myVariable = {};
//               ^^

myVariable['option-1'] = 'something';
…
```